# adding object entity framework using many to many relationship

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database like lets say a class Student and a class Course. These two have many to many relationship through a join table, holding ids of these two tables which is hidden in EF the way it supposed to.

First if I add two courses to a student. Like 
    `John.classes.Add(math); John.classes.Add(physics)` where 'John', math and physics are objects of their respective classes. When i save changes, everything happens the ways it should happen. An entry in students table, two entries in courses table and two entries in StudentCourses join table. All good.

But then, when i add another student say 'Bob' with same two classes. `Bob.classes.Add(math); Bob.classes.Add(physics);`It should add a row in students table adding Bob and two rows in StudentCourses join table. This doesn't happen. A row is added to students table but no rows are being added to StudentCourses table giving error of duplicate entry in courses table. Entity Framework is not adding courses because math and physics already exist in courses table but it should add two entries in StudentCourses join table.

A work around this is by adding an id column in join table and use this table as normal table and manually add entries in StudentCourses table. But i dont want to do this, I want to know the actual solution.
[image: this is table schema. Join table is hidden as per EF rules.]
Thanks

Comment: I am using EF6, mvc5 and Mysql database

Comment: Without any idea of how your data is set up, it's a bit difficult to help. Are you saying you've got a table for `Students` and only one that represents the `Courses` (each with a FK to a `Student`? Surely, you would have `Students`, `Courses` and a `StudentsCourses`? It's unclear from your question. Could you show us your schema for the tables in question? Are you using code-first approach?

Comment: As you've described it it should work fine.  Can you include more of your code? Are you doing everything code-first? I just threw together some code that does more or less what you describe, though using SQL server local DB, and it did exactly what I expected. One thing that can help is to log all the SQL output (e.g. `context.Database.Log = msg => Trace.WriteLine(msg)`)

Comment: i have added the schema. The join table is hidden as per EF rules. When i add team which is already in the teams table through first tournament say tour1 by `tourn1.teams.Add(chelsea_FC)`, It does not add team chelsea_FC again through second tournament ==> `tourn2.teams.Add(chelsea_FC)` gives error for duplicate entry.

Comment: Database.Log error:  `-- Failed in 147 ms with error: Duplicate entry 100' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by

```
team ct = context.teams.Find(club.id);

if (ct == null)
{ comp.teams.Add(club); }
else
{ ct.competitions.Add(comp); }

context.SaveChanges();
```

where comp is competition object. 
I am sure this is not the actual solution but just a way around. This can't be...